# Padding at the top of a table cell in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I have a simple LaTeX `tabular` table:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  A  & B  & C \\
  \hline
  A1 & B1 & C1 \\
  \hline
  A2 & B2 & C2 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: the rendered table]

Now the padding at the top of the cells is much smaller than the padding at the bottom, I guess because space for descenders is reserved. It makes the text look unaligned. How do I add some padding at the top of the table cells? I tried `\arraystretch` but it also adds padding at the bottom.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One way to get better-looking tables while still using vertical rules is to insert "struts" in selected rows to improve the spacing around horizontal lines. (This was suggested by Claudio Beccari in a piece published in 1993 in *TeX and TUG News*.) The idea is to insert "top struts" in rows that have an `\hline` above them, a "bottom strut" in rows that have an `\hline` below them, and both top and bottom struts in rows -- such as header rows -- that have `\hline`s both above and below them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Define "struts" as suggested by Claudio Beccari in
% a piece in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993.
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand{\TBstrut}{\Tstrut\Bstrut} % top&bottom struts
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  A  & B  & C \TBstrut\\ % top and bottom struts
  \hline
  A1 & B1 & C1 \Tstrut\\ % top strut only
  A2 & B2 & C2 \Bstrut\\ % bottom strut only
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

That said, I believe one is more likely to produce good-looking tables if one (i) doesn't use vertical rules at all and (ii) uses the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package and its commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` instead of `\hline` to create horizontal lines. Note that the `\[xxx]rule` lines don't all have the same widths and that there's good spacing around them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  A  & B  & C \\
  \midrule
  A1 & B1 & C1 \\
  A2 & B2 & C2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course... somehow my brain forgot about struts (a common tool in TeX) as soon as I was trying to use LaTeX. I'm not sure if it works with `p` columns, but I will see.

Comment: @AndreKR - Top struts should work just fine with `p`-type columns.

Comment: They do, wonderful. :)

Comment: \toprule did the job for me!

Comment: `\midrule` breaks up vertical lines declared in `\begin{tabular}{l|c|r}`. Any way around this?

Comment: @BallpointBen - Short answer: "No." Longer answer (excerpting from p. 5 of the package's user guide): "More importantly the rules generated by the new commands [such as `\toprule` and `\midrule`] are in no way guaranteed to connect with verticals generated by `|` characters [in the preamble of the `tabular` environment]. This is a feature (see above). You should not use vertical rules in tables, end of story." The "see above" is a reference to an earlier passage, where the author laid down his main rule: "Never, ever use vertical rules".

Answer (score 19):

You can add extra vertical spacing at the top using `\extrarowheight` from the `array` package; the following example presents three options: the first one, your table; the second one, the same table, but setting `\extrarowheight` to `2pt`, adding `2pt` to every row height, but keeping the depth unchanged; the third option, using the `booktabs` package (spacing is much better now by default, but no vertical rules):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  A  & B  & C \\
  \hline
  A1 & B1 & C1 \\
  \hline
  A2 & B2 & C2 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

{
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  A  & B  & C \\
  \hline
  A1 & B1 & C1 \\
  \hline
  A2 & B2 & C2 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  A  & B  & C \\
  \midrule
  A1 & B1 & C1 \\
  A2 & B2 & C2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest `cals` package, which is vebose but makes many things automatically:

[image: simple cals table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}}
\brow \cell{A} \cell{B} \cell{C}  \erow
\brow \cell{A1}\cell{B1}\cell{C1} \erow
\brow \cell{A2}\cell{B2}\cell{C2} \erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```