# Table cell height too small when wrapping text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, tabu, height

I have the following problem with my table:

The height of the 2nd row is slightly too small and the text overlaps with the line at the bottom and the top of the cell.
My code is below:

```
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {| m{0.41\textwidth} | m{0.53\textwidth} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{Static (stuff)} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Dynamic (stuff)} \\ \hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\endlastfoot 
textetxtetxtexttext & textetxtetxtexttext$-$Buffer: X\textbackslash Y\textbackslash y\textbackslash G\textbackslash X\textbackslash H\textbackslash J\textbackslash x00$-$\\ \hline 
textetxtetxtexttext & textetxtetxtexttext$-$Information: XYZ\textbackslash x00 ???\\ \hline   
\caption{calls}
\label{tab:alls}% 
\end{longtabu}
```

Any help is appreciated. Using packages tabu, booktabs and longtable.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add struts to the beginning and end of your columns as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\aefrontstrut}{\rule{0pt}{0.8\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\aebackstrut}{\rule[-0.6\baselineskip]{0pt}{0.8\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {| m{0.41\textwidth} | >{\aefrontstrut}m{0.53\textwidth}<{\aebackstrut} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{Static (stuff)} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Dynamic (stuff)} \\ \hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\endlastfoot 
textetxtetxtexttext & textetxtetxtexttext$-$Buffer: X\textbackslash Y\textbackslash y\textbackslash G\textbackslash X\textbackslash H\textbackslash J\textbackslash x00$-$\\ \hline 
textetxtetxtexttext & textetxtetxtexttext$-$Information: XYZ\textbackslash x00 ???\\ \hline   
\caption{calls}
\label{tab:alls}% 
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

You can use LaTeX's own `\strut` command, or you can make your own customized struts as I've done above.  By using two different style struts and the `>` and `<` modifiers for columns, you can control the spacing above the first line and after the last line in that column.

[image]

By changing the height of the first strut and the depth of the second strut, you can finely control the spacing.

```
\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<height>}
```

Technically, the optional argument to `\rule` is not the depth; it's a dimension by which the rule is raised or lowered.  By using a negative value you are essentially setting the depth of the strut.  Since the strut should not be visible, make sure the `<width>` is set to `Opt`.

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments below, the alignment can be off if the last column contains some short text.  To get around this, use the `>` `<` directives for both columns:

```
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {| >{\aefrontstrut}m{0.41\textwidth}<{\aebackstrut} | >{\aefrontstrut}m{0.53\textwidth}<{\aebackstrut} |}
```

Comment: Thanks, This almost works, but now if there is only one line in the 2nd column it is top aligned vertically not centered?

Comment: Add the directives to all the columns.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The parameter `\baselineskip` sometimes gets messed with by authors who need to change the line spacing of their documents. (I know, they really shouldn't be affecting the line space by modifying `\baselineskip`, but enough people seem to do it anyway to make this a problem to be reckoned with.) To increase the generality/robustness of your answer, you may want to express the heights and depths of the struts as multiples of a font-related parameter such as `ex` rather than as multiples of `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @Mico Excellent point.

Comment: For another recent posting involving the use of struts to provide padding in cells of a tabular environment, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126542/5001 (shameless self-citation alert!).