# Arithmetic/calculations with lengths

Tags: spacing, calculations, lengths

I want to define a new command to add vertical "padding" before and after the content of a table cell. I'm stealing the idea of using rules/struts from the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126539/padding-at-the-top-of-a-table-cell-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1).

My concept is something like

```
\newcommand{\vpad}[2]{
   \rule{0pt}{\baselineskip + #1}              % top padding
   \rule[-0.4*\baselineskip - #2]{0pt}{0pt}}   % bottom padding
```

I know that there are many cases where this won't work, but that's not the issue, at present. My question is about the arithmetic expressions involving `\baselineskip` and the command arguments. Clearly I don't have the syntax correct. So, what is the right syntax for this sort of thing?

**Edit**
I'm starting to think that things like `0.4*baselineskip - #2` are not allowed. If so, maybe I have to settle for '-4pt - #2'. Is negation allowed?

Comment: There's a package dedicated to it: `cellspace` . Do you want to reinvent the wheel? :o)

Comment: @Bernard -- Yes, I'm OK with re-inventing the wheel if my wheel better suits my needs. But, anyway, the real point of the question is not cell spacing, it's the syntax of arithmetic expressions.

Comment: You can try  something like`\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+#1\relax}`. But you also can  load the `bigstrut` package, or the`\setcellgapes{xx}\makegapedcells` command from  `makecell`.

Comment: @Bernard -- That seems to work. Thank you. What about the second one: ` -0.4*\baselineskip - #2`

Comment: Similar: `\rule[-\dimexpr 0.4\baselineskip+#2\relax]{0pt}{0pt}`

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to calculate equations in (La)TeX. (Therefore I created the `adjcalc` package as part of the `adjustbox` bundle so that users can select which way they want it.).

You can either 1) use [eTeX macros](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/etex_man.pdf) like `\dimexpr`, `\glueexpr`, 2) the [`calc` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/calc.pdf) or 3) the [`pgfmath` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

The simplest thing is to use `\dimexpr ... \relax`. It expands to the calculation result. The `\relax` can be used as an endmarker which is also removed in the expansion. This requires eTeX (extended TeX) which is part of all main TeX distributions.

```
\newcommand{\vpad}[2]{
   \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip + #1\relax}              % top padding
   \rule[\dimexpr-0.4*\baselineskip - #2\relax]{0pt}{0pt}}   % bottom padding
```