How to Increase a Length in Inches by a Point without Manual Conversion?
Consider the code:
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   
    \textcolor{red}{\rule{4.625in}{0.125in}}
    
    \textcolor{red}{\rule{4.625in}{0.125in}}
\end{document}

which produces

I would like to increase the length of the second colored strip (of 4.625") by 1 point.
QUESTION: Is there a convenient way of doing this without resorting to converting, say, inches into points or visa-versa and then expressing the desired length either in terms of points or inches? \textcolor{red}{\rule{4.625in}{0.125in+1pt}}does not work.
Thank you.

Instead of \dimexpr…\relax I recommend the (more or less) new LaTeX command \dimeval{…}. See LaTeX for authors current version section 5.

Use \dimeval.
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{color}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{\rule{\dimeval{1.625in+1pt}}{0.125in}}

\textcolor{red}{\rule{1.625in}{0.125in}}

\end{document}

I reduced the width just to make a smaller picture.


Could you please add an answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357961/arithmetic-calculations-with-lengths so we have a place to link future questions to?

Thank you. I was not aware of the \dimeval command.
