# How to change the left padding for one latex table's cell?

Tags: tables, cell

Given the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
a & b & c \\ \hline
d & e & f \\ \hline
g & h & i \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

I could find the question [Padding at the top of a table cell in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126539/padding-at-the-top-of-a-table-cell-in-latex), saying about changing it for a top of the whole table.

How to set the left padding for the column `a` and for the cell `f` to 0, while keeping the rest of the cells and columns with default settings?

Comment: Why do you "accept" the very first (good) answer almost immediately? (You can always up-vote a good answer right away, of course.) If you waited a bit longer (say, 4 or 5 hours) before accepting an answer, you wouldn't be discouraging other answers from being posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|@{}l|l|l|}
\hline
a & b & c \\ \hline
d & e & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l|}{f} \\ \hline
g & h & i \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**  an above example is not moved content to left border of table but left border to content. Consequently, column is for `\tabcolsep` narrower (thank  *Mico* for comment). For preserving equal column width (if this is requested) , this width can be added on the end of cell:

```
 \begin{tabular}{|@{}l@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|l|l|}
```

which in treated case give:

[image]

Comment: Observe that this approach has the side effect of makin the first column narrower, in the amount of `\tabcolsep`. It may be worth pointing out this side-effect explicitly.

Comment: @Mico, yo have right (again) :)

Comment: @chzzh, for cell `f`` you had to change content align locally. The only way to get showed result is to use `multicolumn` command. What you mean with "not wrap"

Comment: @chzzh, it is not clear (to me), what is your problem. Please. asl new question and explain what you like to achieve.